# How to Prevent EF5 LocalDB Connection From Closing

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, localdb

I've built an applciation using EF5 and CodeFirst.  At runtime my application creates a LocalDB databse file and a class-level instance of a DataContext.  Everything works fine however inserts are slow after about 50,000 records (approx 20MB MDF file).  In debug I can see the internal Connection's state is set to 'Closed'.  I assume EF5 is closing the connection after each insert and then re-opening it when needed.

How can I prevent Entity Framework from closing the connection?  This is a local that will potentially need to import up to 500k records in the shortest period of time.

Looking at the State of the Connection shows frequent changes.  The string to the left is a date stamp in yyyyMMddHHmmssfff format...

- 20130818072134139 : Original: Open / Current: Closed
- 20130818072134160 : Original: Closed / Current: Open
- 20130818072134163 : Original: Open / Current: Closed
- 20130818072134185 : Original: Closed / Current: Open
- 20130818072134188 : Original: Open / Current: Closed
- 20130818072134209 : Original: Closed / Current: Open
- 20130818072134212 : Original: Open / Current: Closed
- 20130818072134246 : Original: Closed / Current: Open

These are just a small snippet from the same ONE SECOND.  This must be [at least] part of the slow inserts.

Comment: Can you please edit your question if you have more details, its really hard to read in comments

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with opening and closing connections.  You appear to have jumped to the wrong conclusion, and are racing to solve the wrong problem.  In fact, LocalDb has no connections, since it's a local file based database.

Your problem is that you have a class level data context.  Entity Framework data contexts are designed to be short lived.  They have no real resource management, and they assume that once a transaction is done you will dispose and destroy it.

Your problem, of getting slow after a period of time is common when you do not destroy the data context after every transaction, as the context keeps growing larger and larger, and allocating and re-allocating memory.  As the context gets larger, EF must walk the list of records in the local cache each time SaveChanges is called, and as more and more records are inserted, this takes longer and longer.

I suggest you rethink your design on this.  You have several options, the first of which is to simply do as I suggested and destroy the context after every transaction.  The second, is to bypass the model completely if you are simply doing inserts and use a straight sql command using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` or even better, use Sql Bulk inserts instead.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you are keeping the objects around and bloating the Context.  You may be able to prove this by using Task Manager and watching the memory usage.  It will probably be growing in size.

If you do not need the objects any longer then DETACH them from the context as soon as you are through.  You could use a Repository to do this quite easily.

First, the code to detach them...

```
GenericRepository<Path> repo = new GenericRepository<Path>(context);
repo.Detach(item);
```

Next, the generic repository...

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
    protected DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("An instance of DbContext is " +
                "required to use this repository.", "context");
        }

        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = this.Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            this.DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            this.DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            this.DbSet.Attach(entity);
            this.DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = this.GetById(id);

        if (entity != null)
        {
            this.Delete(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Detach(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = this.Context.Entry(entity);

        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: AWESOME!  THANKS!  I dropped this in an cut my time by almost 100%!  This morning 500k records took about 10 HOURS on a VM.  After including the code above it took about 5 MINUTES!  =)